# SlidingDrawer animation velocity

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I'm new to Android programming and to stack overflow, and I need to slow down the animation speed of a SlidingDrawer in my app.

I've already subclassed SlidingDrawer like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;

public class WrappingSlidingDrawer extends SlidingDrawer {

public WrappingSlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    int orientation = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "orientation", ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    mTopOffset = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "topOffset", 0);
    mVertical = (orientation == SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
}

public WrappingSlidingDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    int orientation = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "orientation", ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    mTopOffset = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("android", "topOffset", 0);
    mVertical = (orientation == SlidingDrawer.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int widthSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSpecSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSpecSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (widthSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED || heightSpecMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SlidingDrawer cannot have UNSPECIFIED dimensions");
    }

    final View handle = getHandle();
    final View content = getContent();
    measureChild(handle, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mVertical) {
        int height = heightSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredHeight() - mTopOffset;
        content.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, heightSpecMode));
        heightSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredHeight() + mTopOffset + content.getMeasuredHeight();
        widthSpecSize = content.getMeasuredWidth();
        if (handle.getMeasuredWidth() > widthSpecSize) widthSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
    else {
        int width = widthSpecSize - handle.getMeasuredWidth() - mTopOffset;
        getContent().measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, widthSpecMode), heightMeasureSpec);
        widthSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredWidth() + mTopOffset + content.getMeasuredWidth();
        heightSpecSize = content.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (handle.getMeasuredHeight() > heightSpecSize) heightSpecSize = handle.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(widthSpecSize, heightSpecSize);
}

private boolean mVertical;
private int mTopOffset;
```

}

I found this link: [How to change animation velocity on SlidingDrawer](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a7d0102811474bfe), and it says that I can find an alternative implementation, or copy the source and modify it.

I created SlidingDrawer.java in my own project and pasted the code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java.htm), but there are errors. There are several lines that reference R.styleable.SlidingDrawer, e.g.

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.SlidingDrawer, defStyle, 0);
```

which Eclipse can't resolve.

There are also four member variables (mTop, mBottom, mLeft, mRight) which Eclipse can't resolve.

How do I make Eclipse find these resources/variables? I will then be able to edit some variables to result in a slower animation, right?

Comment: hey can you please provide the final custom class, and how you add it into xml, because it is giving me error "InflateException".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe R.styleable was removed from the sdk, you can write your own though, something like this should work

In the values folder create an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MySlider"> 
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_orientation"  format="integer"/>
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_bottomOffset" format = "dimension"/>
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_topOffset" format = "dimension"/>
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_allowSingleTap" format = "boolean"/>
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_animateOnClick" format = "boolean"/>
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_handle" format = "reference"/>
        <attr name = "SlidingDrawer_content" format = "reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then in the slider class you can reference the xml file

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MySlider, defStyle, 0);

int orientation = a.getInt(R.styleable.MySlider_SlidingDrawer_orientation, ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
//...etc. ...
```

I am also extending the slidingdrawer class and this works for me.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solved my problem, I can now get on with extending the class.

Comment: Do you mean the `mTop`, `mBottom`, etc. just use their getters - `getTop()`, `getBottom()`, etc