# Reducing sliding drawer velocity

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I have included sliding drawer in my code. wanted to make it animate bit slower then the actual velocity. do anyone know how to reduce the velocity? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

According to everything I have read, you would need to re-create the SlidingDrawer class in your app 
and make your modifications there.

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884917/slidingdrawer-animation-velocity) about this.

And a link to the [SlidingDrawer class](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java.htm).

Hope this helps and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should be see the following link:

1. [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)
2. [SlidingDrawer animation velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884917/slidingdrawer-animation-velocity)

And you should be use `animateToggle()` for this.