# how can i slow down the animation of the slidingdrawer

Tags: android, performance, slidingdrawer

i already seen the link [slidingdrawer-animation-velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884917/slidingdrawer-animation-velocity) and i have already copy the source slidingdrawer and modify the value of

```
private static final int ANIMATION_FRAME_DURATION = 1500 / 60;
```

but it only effect the delay time of the animation,not the animation duration? is there any other method to change the speed of slidingdrawer?

Comment: show your codes please

Comment: codes are simple,just the source code of slidingdrawer,and i changed the line 92.the codes are too long to copy here.